# Reading JSON format from URL

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to make a website that analyzes data from a game called Overwatch.

I have this (https://enhanced-ow-api.herokuapp.com/ShalevBito-2753/competetive/pc/us/) and when you visit it, all you see is text in the json format.

Is there anyway I can read this using JavaScript and send it to a nice `<p>` tag on my website?

Current Code:

```
<script>
var obj = JSON.parse('https://enhanced-ow-api.herokuapp.com/ShalevBito-2753/competetive/pc/us/');
document.getElementById("elims").innerHTML = obj.Eliminations;
</script>
<p id="elims"></p>
```

Comment: That aint how JSON.parse works....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't tag this with jQuery so I'm going to assume you're wanting to do this with vanilla JS. `.jsonParse()` doesn't actually request JSON from a URL--it parses existing JSON-data into an object.

To handle this, you'll first want to request the data. This can be done using an [XMLHttpRequest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest):

`var requestUrl = "https://enhanced-ow-api.herokuapp.com/ShalevBito-2753/competetive/pc/us/";`

You next want to build out and perform your request. Create a `function` once the JSON data is fully loaded (`onload`):

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestUrl);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();
request.onload = function() {
    logData(request.response);
}
```

An example function that handles the data could be:

```
function logData(data) { 
    document.querySelector('.elims').innerText = `Genji Eliinations: ${data['Genji']["Combat"]["Eliminations"]}`;
}
```

This appends it to an element with the class `.elims`, for example, a

tag:

`<p class="elims"></p>`

I've added the whole code below. This should be enough to get you in the correct direction:

```js
let requestUrl = "https://enhanced-ow-api.herokuapp.com/ShalevBito-2753/competetive/pc/us/";
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestUrl);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();
request.onload = function() {
 logData(request.response);
}

function logData(data) { 
 document.querySelector('.elims').innerText = `Genji Eliinations: ${data['Genji']["Combat"]["Eliminations"]}`;
}
```

```html
<p class="elims">

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good way to start, so the URL you are trying to access is the REST web service which is just a GET method which produces the JSON. All you have to do is make an AJAX call via Javascript or Jquery and you can parse this to a Javascript variable then you can use those variable values you can generate the Paragraph elements to your HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load data from server using HTTP GET request like this,

```
$.get( "https://enhanced-ow-api.herokuapp.com/ShalevBito-2753/competetive/pc/us/", function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
  //process your data here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your url (`https://enhanced-ow-api.herokuapp.com/ShalevBito-2753/competetive/pc/us/`) is in json format. In order to retrieve it you need to use something like getJson.

**Example:**

```
$.getJSON( "https://enhanced-ow-api.herokuapp.com/ShalevBito-2753/competetive/pc/us/", function( json ) {
  console.log( "JSON Data: " + json.Assists["Healing Done"]);
 });
```

You can read more on how to use [getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).